# Backport of RTTI.TRttiIndexedProperty to Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rtti

**Facts:**

Successfull independent efforts to bring **Rtti.TVirtualInterface** introduced in Delphi XE2 to prior Delphi versions were made respectively by

- Vincent Parrett in `Delphi.Mocks.VirtualInterface` unit ([Delphi Mocks](https://github.com/VSoftTechnologies/Delphi-Mocks))
- Stefan Glienke in `DSharp.Core.VirtualInterface.pas` unit ([DSharp](https://code.google.com/p/delphisorcery/))

---

**Findings:**

- TRttiIndexedProperty is derived from TRttiMember.
- TRttiType and TRttiInstanceType depend on TRttiIndexedProperty.
- Rtti.pas depends on TypInfo.pas where some breaking changes where also introduced.

---

**Question:**

Is there a hope that one day someone will make it possible to bring TRttiIndexedProperty on Delphi XE ?

Comment: What does this question have to do with clean-room implementations?

Comment: @Rob Now it is a answer.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy: Header rephrased.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TRttiIndexedProperty can't be back-ported to older Delphi versions because it depends on the compiler writing out RTTI data for indexed properties, what only Delphi XE2's compiler does. You can't read something that isn't there.

The only possibility you have would be to write this data by hand. So you have to write a parser that runs over all your code and generates the necessary type information for all indexed properties. And because your parser isn't the compiler you would also have to write little helper functions that write and read the indexed-property.
The output could be something like this:

```
TMyClass = class
private
  ...
public
  property MyArray[Index: Integer]: TMyObject read GetMyArray write SetMyArray;

  // autogenerated code
  class procedure RegisterIndexedPropertyInfos(Registry: TMyRttiIndexedPropertyRegistry); static;
end;

// autogenerated code
class procedure TMyClass.RegisterIndexedPropertyInfos(Registry: TMyRttiIndexedPropertyRegistry): TMyRttiIndexedProperty;
begin
  Registry.Register('MyArray', [TMyRttiIndex.Create('Index', TypeInfo(Integer))], TypeInfo(TMyObject), @TMyClass.GetMyArray, @TMyClass.SetMyArray);
end;

// When using RichRTTI you can omit this line and use the the RttiContext to find RegisterIndexedPropertyInfos
RegisterIndexedPropertyClass(TMyClass, @TMyClass.RegisterIndexedPropertyInfos);
```